# How do I get data from Firebase collection using NextJs API, Firebase Firestore, axios and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, api, next.js

I'm using api routes in NextJS 13, to fetch data from Firebase like this(`api/locations.tsx`):

```
import { db } from "../../firebase";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const Locations = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    const locationsSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "locations"));
    const locationsData = locationsSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));

    res.status(200).json({ locationsData });
  } catch {
    res.status(400).end();
  }
};

export default Locations;
```

Then I have a component `Locations.tsx` where I'm trying to store the locations in `locations` state object like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  Container,
  Content,
  Main,
  StyledLink,
  Title,
} from "../components/sharedstyles";
import axios from "axios";

export type LocationData = {
  film: string;
  imdbId: string;
  location?: string;
  scene?: string;
  coords: [number, number];
}[];

type GetLocationResponse = { data: { locationsData: LocationData[] } };

export default function About() {
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState([]);

  const getLocations = async () => {
    // Fetch locations data from locations endpoint and return location data
    const res = await axios.get<GetLocationResponse>("/api/locations");

    return res.data.locationsData;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocations(getLocations());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Main>
        <Title>Locations</Title>
        <Content>
          <ul>
            {locations?.map(({ location }) => (
              <li>{location}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </Content>
        <Link href="/" passHref legacyBehavior>
          <StyledLink>&larr; Home</StyledLink>
        </Link>
      </Main>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

But I'm getting an error `Property 'locationsData' does not exist on type 'GetLocationResponse'.` even though I tried adding "locationsData" to my type definition `type GetLocationResponse = { data: { locationsData: LocationData[] } };`

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and how I might resolve it? Please and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your frontend is expecting a response object with a `data` property:

```
type GetLocationResponse = { data: { locationsData: LocationData[] } };
```

But your backend is sending and object with only a property `locationsData`:

```
res.status(200).json({ locationsData });
```

Perhaps you want the frontend's expectations to match what the backend is sending by dropping the `data` property:

```
type GetLocationResponse = { locationsData: LocationData[] };
```

Comment: Thanks Doug! That was the source of the error alright, I'm pretty new to Typescript and now facing a new error

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should post an entirely new question.  By changing the question, you have invalidated the answer you were given about the first problem (which might be helpful for other in the future).  The normal etiquette is to mark the answer as correct so others can learn and benefit from the first issue. I went ahead and reverted the post to its original content.

Comment: Ok,I hadn’t thought of that, thanks!